# Query ignoring the WHERE clause when i have sum

Tags: php, sql, where-clause

SQL Query: `SELECT sum(value) as valuee FROM table_name WHERE id = $id_session AND year = $year`

This query is giving me nothing.

But if i do it like this:

`SELECT sum(value) as valuee FROM table_name`  - works without the WHERE clauses.

Comment: A `WHERE` clause works fine with `SUM`. Your issue is none of your records match the conditions in the `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably not setting the `$id_session` or `$year` properly. Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT sum(value) as valuee FROM table_name WHERE id = '$id_session' AND year = '$year'";
echo $sql;
```

***EDIT***

To save future visitors some time, this was the end result as posted by OP in the comments:

`i had the wrong table name phpmyadmin. Now it is fine`

Comment: It may be better using `WHERE id = '$id_session' AND year = '$year'`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Correct you are, especially for MySQL. I think some DBMSs have an issue with querying a literal string against an INT DB field type.

Comment: That's what I think as well. I see this all too often where the OP isn't wrapping variables correctly. There are other ways of doing it, but my comment is but one way of doing it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yep! Ever since I learned how to use PDO properly, I have not looked back for a single second.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Same here, however I do like to dabble with `MySQLi_` also. Keeps me "sharp" ;-)

Comment: @DiogoSantos Oh haha, well maybe someday I'll become psychic or maybe just hack your DB to check the table name in the future lol. Thanks for the Correct Answer Vote!

Comment: @Fred-ii- I skipped `MySQLi_` completely. Went from `MySQL_` straight to `new PDO()`. I admit it was a bit tough but totally worth it especially when I prepare the query (available with both mysqli_ and PDO) and think to myself "Wow I can't believe I used to manually sanitize all these values (via a custom PHP function)"